# Prove on residue theorem

Tags: residue-calculus

I have try to use the equation 
$$
Res(f;z_0)=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac1{(m-1)!}\frac{d^{m-1}}{dz^{m-1}}[(z-z_0)^mf(z)]
$$
But very soon I stuck, is that a good way to solve it?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few hints:

1) Since you have a double pole at $z=z_0$, your $f$ has the form

$$f(z) = \frac{p(z)}{(z-z_0)^2 r(z)}$$

i.e., $q(z) = (z-z_0)^2 r(z)$, where $r$ is analytic at $z=z_0$.

2) Use the given expression for the residue with $m=2$.  This means you will be taking the derivative of $p(z)/r(z)$.

3) Finally, you need things in terms of $q$, not $r$, you need to evaluate the second and third derivatives of $q(z)=(z-z_0)^2 r(z)$ at $z=z_0$.  This will give you expressions for $r(z_0)$ and $r'(z_0)$ as needed if you did everything right in step 2).

Comment: After I find out$$ r(z_0) $$and $$r'(z_0) $$and sub into the formula, it still far away from the question
$$
\frac{P'(z)(z-z_0)^3}{Q'(z)(z-z_0)-2Q(z)}
$$
Is there something goes wrong?

Comment: You have to plug in $z=z_0$ into the derivative formula.  For example, $$q'(z) = 2 (z-z_0) r(z) + (z-z_0)^2 r'(z)$$ so that $q'(z_0)=0$.  What about the second and third derivatives of $q$?

Comment: $$
Q"(z_0)=2r(z_0),
Q"'(z_0)=2r'(z_0)
$$
But how can a single term,the derivative of P(z)/r(z), expand to two terms? It is still quite far from the question.

Comment: @user111605: do you know the quotient rule?  I hope so if you are studying this stuff.